# Why does the following code give a classcast exception?

Tags: java, inheritance

Given below piece of code:

```
//Super class 
class A {
    void m1() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

//Extending the super class  
class B extends A {
    void m1() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

// Class with the main method
public class C extends B {
    void m1() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}

//in some main method
B b1 = new B(); //creating B object
System.out.println(b1 instanceof A); //gives true
B b = (B) new A();
b.m1();
```

1. The `instanceof` operator gives true so `B` is a object of class `A`.
2. But why while casting `A` to `B` its gives `ClassCastException` even though `B` is an sub-type of `A`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new A();` is simply not `B`.

It's the same as you were saying that "Every Animal is a Cat with no exceptions". Which is not true.

However, casting `B` to `A` would be correct (because every Cat is an Animal, with no exceptions):

```
A a = (A) new B();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A a = new B(); // is fine as B inherits A
B b = new A(); // is NOT fine as A does not inherit any thing from B
```

Answer (score 0):

B is an instance of A that is right. But A is not an instance of B. That's why you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`B b = (B) new A();` is the wrong statement cause `A` doesn't inherits `B`; rather `B` inherits `A`

Answer (score 0):

Allowing such casting would not be safe for few reasons.

1) Lets say that you added in your `B` additional method of field which `A` doesn't have like

```
class A {
    void m1() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void m1() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

    private int x;
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Now lets assume that this casting will work

```
B b = (B) new A();
```

So `b` will hold instance of `A`. But later we can try invoking `setX` from `B` reference

```
b.setX(1);
```

which should be fine because there was no casting exception so object from `B` reference should be able to support this call.
What do you think, how should JVM react on this next line? Should such code be allowed?

No, base `A` doesn't know how which code should be executed for `setX` and even if it knew it, it doesn't have `int x` field to store its data. So to prevent such situations JVM throws ClassCastException.

---

2) You can say that: "*OK, but my `B` doesn't change interface, it doesn't add anything new to `A`*". You are right, but allowing casting in this case is also dangerous, because while invoked methods from `B` you should be able to expect that they will behave in a way described in `B` class, or its subclasses.

Lets say that we are building racing game and we have classes

```
class Car{
    int getMaxSpeed(){
        200;
    }
}
class LimitedSpeedCar extends Car{
    int getMaxSpeed(){
        return 30;
    }
}
```

Now you want to create racing track only for cars with limited speed. So you are creating `LimitedSpeedCar[]` array to store only cars with limited speed. But guess what, because

```
B b = (B) new A();
```

works fine it means that

```
LimitedSpeedCar lsc = (LimitedSpeedCar) new Car();
```

will also work so we can add to our race car without limits which is not what we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

`B` is a subclass of `A`, you cannot cast `A` to `B`. In fact, maybe the concrete class of the new `A` Object is another class than `B`(let say a class `C` that extends `A`). So you cannot affirm that `A` is an instance of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

An object of type B can be cast to variable of type A but not the other way around.  B extends A so it could potentially have more functionality. This might be a good time to go back and read up on polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

You can't down cast an object. You can create a

`A a1 = new B()`.

But you can't create a

`B b1 = new A()`

It's simple like every German Shepard is a Dog. So you can create a new German Shepard dog.

But you can't be sure that every Dog is a German Shepard. Hence creating a new German Shepard of type dog is not supported.
Read [This](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/50451-upcasting-downcasting/)